# C++ destructor: when the memory gets freed?

Tags: c++, destructor

If I delete an object which causes its destructor to be called, does the memory get freed before or after the destructor has finished doing whatever there is in the function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Memory is only freed once the least derived class subobject has been destroyed. So if you have:

```
class Base {
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    ~Derived();
};
```

then first `Derived` is destroyed, then `Base` is destroyed and only then memory is deallocated.

Comment: Is there actually such a thing? A particular destructor is called, which may be virtual if the class declared it as such. That destructor is responsible for destroying all subobjects, and then the memory is freed. All subobjects without base classes are equally least-derived, and none have particular responsibility or significance.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Note I haven't specified who exactly is responsible for calling the deallocation function - exactly because doing so in all details would require a two-pages answer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I am not sure I follow. No destructor is responsible for destroying subobjects. The destructor is responsible for freeing the resources held in that object, but does not have to (nor should it) call the destructor of other objects: `class test { string a; ~test() {} };` The `~test` destructor is perfectly defined in this example, there is no resource directly managed by the class and does nothing. The system will call `~string` on the `a` subobject after `~test` has completed execution, not `~test`. The same goes with inheritance, base's destructor will be automatically called.

Comment: ... note that what has to be dealt with is getting the *most derived class* 's destructor to get called. After that is achieved, the system will ensure that all of the `base`'s destructor get called in reverse order of construction. Going back to the responsibility, if a member holds a resource that needs specific management and that is not held by that type's destructor --think a pointer that needs *delete* -ing and being a pointer has no destructor-- then that resource has to be managed in the containing class.

Comment: @David:  "No destructor is responsible for destroying subobjects."  Well, not explicitly, no:  you don't have to explicitly call `this->~Base()` inside of `~Derived()`.  However, at least the way it's formally defined, `~Derived()` is responsible for calling `this->~Base()` (and `a.~string()` in your comment example).  When you use `delete`, one destructor gets called and that destructor is responsible for calling all cleanup, including by calling any base class or member destructors if so needed.

Comment: @sharptooth: The problem is that there is no single least derived subobject. It would be better to say "after all subobjects have been destroyed, which occurs after the function body of the destructor."

Answer (score 4):

Decompose `delete` into what it is actually doing and it is relatively clear to see when the memory is deleted. So a statement like this:

```
delete some_ptr;
```

Is roughly equivalent to this pseudo-code:

```
some_ptr->~some_ptr();
free( some_ptr );
```

So the memory is freed after the call to the destructor. Exactly what the destructor does is not determined by the `delete` operator, but rather the definition of the class. Usually it does local cleanup and ensures that its base class destructors are also called.

It is important to realize that freeing the memory is not actually part of the destructor. It is the `delete` operator which frees the memory.

---

Note that the `free` function in pseudo-code is actually one of the `operator delete()`  functions, either for the deleted class, or global. That actually frees up the memory.

Comment: That's not `free()`, that's `operator delete()`.

Comment: @sharptooth, can you clarify? I did mention that was 'pseudo-code'.

Comment: Even if it's pseudocode C++ uses `operator delete()` - either global or class-specific - for deallocating memory upon `delete` statement.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, though for the pseudo code I think "free" is clearer in understanding (not to have a recursive delete in there)

Comment: @sharptooth: Its hard to describe an operator in terms of itself. The use of free() as an example is acceptable as long as you mention it is pseudocode . Though I would have used release() to prevent confusion with any specific API.

Comment: @Martin York: Well, yes, there's a tendency to confuse `delete` statement with `operator delete()` function. I guess you're right - something like `deallocateMemory()` would be better for pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

The memory gets freed after the destructor has finished. Otherwise, accessing member variables inside the destructor would cause segfaults.

Answer (score 2):

operator delete is called after destructor, but when the memory is freed is up to used allocator

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the memory is freed after the destructor function itself has finished executing. I know that when an exception is caught, the destructor to the object is not called until the object itself goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, destruction is about executing some code using the data available in the object. This code is arbitrary.

Free'ing the memory is a low level handling, hidden by the `delete` operator in general, that should never be called prior to calls to the destructor.

This is best summarized by the [Allocator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/) interface:

- `allocate` and `deallocate` are used to manipulate raw memory
- `construct` and `destroy` are used to call the constructors and destructors of the objects

It is precised that `construct`, `destroy` and `deallocate` should only be executed on memory previously allocated by that allocator. It also precises that `destroy` does not deallocate the memory, and that a subsequent call to `deallocate` will be necessary.

Note that this is a low-level interface, which allow destroying an object and reusing the freed space to construct another in place.