# At which point of destructor call the object ceases to exist?

Tags: c++

When a destructor of an object is called, at which point does the object cease to exist?
Does it happen in the moment when its called? or after it finishes deleting the memory of the object's members inside the function?
I'm mainly asking it in order to understand if it's legal to call an object's function inside its destructor or not

Comment: That depends on what that function does. What does it do? It would be good if you can [edit] with some code giving context to your question.

Comment: `*this` still points to a valid object while in the destructor. Destructors are really just "pre-destructors" functions, in the same way that constructors are really just "post-constructors" (ignoring the member initializer list).

Comment: You can call your own functions and base class functions as long as they are not virtual.

Comment: You can call methods within the destructor.  At the closing curly brace is when each member variable is destructed (in reverse order from declaration), and then each parent class is destructed (in reverse order from declaration).  (I'm not sure about virtual inheritance, when the common ancestor is destructed.)  The only big caveat is that virtual functions will not call child class override virtual functions, because the child class has already been destructed.

Comment: This is a great question. I don't understand why it has 2 close votes and only 1 upvote.

Comment: @Devolus: You can call your own virtual functions as well. You can't call **pure** virtual functions. Note that in C++, the dynamic type of `*this` in `Foo::~Foo` is `Foo` - even if the object had a derived type before, it no longer does when the dtor runs. That's why you call Foo's virtual functions from `Foo::~Foo`.

Comment: @MSalters, yes, but that may not be what you expect and you have to be aware of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> At which point of destructor call the object ceases to exist?

The lifetime of the object is ended by the call to its destructor. Within the destructor body, the sub-objects are still alive and member functions may be called. After the destructor body, the sub objects are destroyed.

> if it's legal to call an object's function inside its destructor or not

It is legal.

Note however that calling a virtual function works differently than one might expect.

Comment: I'd cite https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#1 which specifies that objects occupy storage during construction and destruction and makes a distinction between these periods and an object's lifetime.

Comment: So for a virtual function it will call the matching one for the class level we're in, right?

Comment: @ItamarIvri Right. If there ever was a more derived class, the lifetime of that derived object has already ended, the destructor body executed, and its sub-objects are now in the process of being destroyed.

Comment: Actually it's in the responsibility of the destructor whether method calls are still valid: At the beginning they definitely are (if they were before), but during destruction (formally speaking now) the class invariant may be violated, making further method calls (on `this` at least) invalid.

Answer (score 0):

We can say that the memory is freed after the destructor function itself has finished executing. See [C++ destructor: when the memory gets freed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793011/c-destructor-when-the-memory-gets-freed/4793037)
However, if not strictly necessary for the deallocation of objects, avoid adding additional logic inside the destructor.

Comment: There is a difference between when an object's lifetime ends and when the memory it occupied is freed. This question is about object lifetime.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux in the link to which I refer there is also a hint of explanation to what you say in the answer of edA-qa mort-ora-y

Comment: *"avoid adding additional logic inside the destructor"* - So what, don't write RAII handlers? Unqualified, this advice is the antithesis of good C++ design.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I was referring to separation of concerns

Comment: It's best to be explicit in what you mean rather than leaving it up for the reader. Otherwise cargo cults form.

Comment: I agree with StoryTeller. The intent might be right, but as worded now this answer is helpfully to nobody. You'd need to know how things work to understand this answer, at which point there's no added value to this answer.

Comment: I tend to agree with "If you don't need a destructor, don't write one."